# How to align the div in header right ,left and center

Tags: html, css

```css
.header-cont
{
 width: 100%;
 position: fixed;
 top: 0px;
}
.header
{
 height: 50px;
 background: #f0f0f0;
 border: 1px solid #ccc;
 width: 80%;
 margin: 0px auto;
 line-height: 0px;

}
.maindiv
{
 box-shadow: 15px 0px 10px -11px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1), -15px 0px 10px -11px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
 width: 960px;
 background: #f0f0f0;
 border: 1px solid #ccc;
 height: 2000px;
 margin: 70px auto;
 
}
label {
    float: left;
    width: 15%;
    margin-top: .5%;

}

form ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
}

form ul li {
    clear: both;
    margin-top:2%;
    
}
```

```html
<html>
<body>
<!-- Star Here Top Title Bar -->
<div class="header-cont">
<div class="header">
<form>
    <ul>
      <li>
      <div>
Here is the logo want to b in left corner
        <label>
          <img src=""> <!-- Logo in left side corner--> `enter code here`
        </label>  
      <div>
      <div >
Here is the profile picture i want to b it in center
        <label> 
          <img src=""><!-- Profile Picture in center -->
        </label>
       </div>
Here is user name wnt to be in right side
        <label>
          <a href="" id="welcome">Welcome User!!</a><!-- Right Side-->
        </label>
Login and sign up want to b in Right corner
        <label>
          <a href="#">Login</a><!-- Right Side Corner-->
          <a href="#">Signup</a>
        </label>
      </li>
    </ul> 
</form>
</div>
</div>
<div class="maindiv">
<h1>This is Content Page</h1>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

[Thiz is output of the program, i want to change this header](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DgT5P.jpg)

Comment: Could you explain the difference between right side and right corner? Do you mean up right corner?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change width according to your need.

```css
    .container{
        width:100%;
    }

    .left {
     float:left;
        width:33.33%;
     text-align: left;
     
    }
    .center {
     display: inline-block;
        margin:0 auto;
        width:33.33%;
        text-align: center;
    }

    .right {
     float:right;
        width:33.33%;
     text-align: right;
    }
```

```html
<div class="container">
<div class="left"><!-- left contents --> </div>
<div class="center"><!-- center contents --> </div>
<div class="right"><!-- right contents --> </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Take 3 `<div>` give them id and `width:33.33%;` give `float:left;`

Inside the 1st div put your logo, in 2nd put the profile picture and in third take 2 more `<div>` of `width:50%;` each and for welcome user set `text-align:left;` and for login and sign up set `text-align:right;`